# Where to download the official Office 2013 to use with a PKC?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, download

We bought a Dell computer with Windows 7 pro + Office 2013 home & business. The disk has failed the day we installed it (hardware failure).
The disk is now replaced, but the Dell technician installed a bare Windows 7.

We have a PKC (Product Key Card) for Office, but I could't find out where I can download the software. I only found "Office Professional Plus" from a Microsoft's site. Other downloads I found are only from no-official websites.

Where can I download an official version of Office Home & Business, usable with a PKC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to [www.office.com/setup](http://www.office.com/setup).
- Enter your 25-digit install key.
- Sign in.
- Follow on-screen instructions to download.

Source: The instructions that come with Office Home and Business 2013 OEM. :)

Comment: Either path I take lead to payment. Either Office 365, either pay before download.

Comment: Oops, screwed that up, doing it that way auto-direct you to what you've keyed in already, which you probably haven't got that far.  I'll edit my answer..

Answer (score 3):

Close but this is what you really need:

If the card with your 25 character Office 2013 product key references a PC manufacturer, please use [www.office.com/getoffice](http://www.office.com/getoffice) to download your new Office product.