# Do Office 2013 OEMs allow for x64 installations?

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-office, oem

Basically what the title says. At my company we order new computers with MS Office OEM pre-installations. As far as I know, there is no option during the installation to select the x64 version of any office component.

Does anyone know of a way to install x64 office with an OEM license?

Comment: Have you tried talking to the system builder to see whether they offer this option?

Comment: Personally I have not, since I am not the one who orders the computers.

Comment: If your company is ordering in bulk there's no reason why whoever's in charge at your end can't ask for the 64-bit version to be pre-installed instead. After all, you're paying for it. If they can't do it for some reason they'll let you know, and then you can start thinking of alternative solutions.

Comment: You're right. But my question has to do with an OEM that is already ordered and is obviously not x64. Are OEMs either x86 or x64? If the answer to that question is yes then that would mean that there is no way to upgrade a x86 OEM to x64.

Comment: Well it has to be either/or, [can't be both](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/why-cant-i-install-both-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office-2013-HA103523746.aspx).

Comment: Well that makes sense, but can I uninstall it and re-install it as x64 from the MS website?

Comment: I believe the same key should work. You can see if the steps detailed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/580295/where-to-download-the-official-office-2013-to-use-with-a-pkc) allow you to download the 64-bit version from MS, but that's hardly the solution I'd recommend for bulk PC purchases in future.

Comment: A given Office 2013 license gives you permisison to install either version.  **Talk to the OEM to provide the media required to install it yourself.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your OEM purchase has to include the Microsoft product key for Office somewhere in the paperwork/email you receive with it. You can then uninstall the 32 bit version and re-install the 64bit version of Office using the same key.

However - Microsoft recommends not using the 64bit version of Office. It doesn't offer any different functionality there is still the same size worksheet dimensions. However, it does allow for larger memory use, so an extremely populated spreadsheet that might have reached a memory limit could be loaded.

Some disadvantages of 64bit Office:

- If you use any 3rd party Office Add-in's, you'll need to get new 64
  bit versions.
- Compatibility with embedding Office docs within/from other 32bit
  apps.
- Rumored slower performance in 64bit (probably only observable by running timing tests at worst)